# Uninitialized Constant :Prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm developing a rails app and deploying it to Heroku. I have the prawn gem installed (it's both in my Gemfile and my Gemfile.lock files). My app deploys correctly but when I try to access a PDF file (generated using prawn) I get an "Application Error" from Heroku. When I check my logs (using heroku logs --tail) this is the output I get:

```
2018-07-30T13:42:29.384992+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/pdfs/pdfmylist_pdf.rb:3:in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Prawn (NameError)
2018-07-30T13:42:29.385045+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/engine.rb:444:inblock (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2018-07-30T13:42:29.385047+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/engine.rb:443:in each'
2018-07-30T13:42:29.385048+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/engine.rb:443:inblock in eager_load!'
2018-07-30T13:42:29.385050+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/engine.rb:441:in each'
2018-07-30T13:42:29.385052+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/engine.rb:441:ineager_load!'
2018-07-30T13:42:29.385060+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in block in <module:Finisher>'
2018-07-30T13:42:29.385061+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:ininstance_exec'
2018-07-30T13:42:29.385063+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in run'
2018-07-30T13:42:29.385064+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:inblock in run_initializers'
2018-07-30T13:42:29.385065+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in each'
2018-07-30T13:42:29.385067+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:inrun_initializers'
2018-07-30T13:42:29.385069+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in initialize!'
2018-07-30T13:42:29.385070+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:inmethod_missing'
2018-07-30T13:42:29.385074+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in <top (required)>'
2018-07-30T13:42:29.385077+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config.ru:3:inrequire'
2018-07-30T13:42:29.385079+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config.ru:3:in block in <main>'
2018-07-30T13:42:29.385080+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:ininstance_eval'
2018-07-30T13:42:29.385082+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in initialize'
2018-07-30T13:42:29.385084+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config.ru:innew'
2018-07-30T13:42:29.385085+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config.ru:in <main>'
2018-07-30T13:42:29.385087+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:ineval'
2018-07-30T13:42:29.385089+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in parse_file'
2018-07-30T13:42:29.385090+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/server.rb:200:inapp'
2018-07-30T13:42:29.385092+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in app'
2018-07-30T13:42:29.385095+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/server.rb:254:instart'
2018-07-30T13:42:29.385093+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in wrapped_app'
2018-07-30T13:42:29.385097+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:instart'
2018-07-30T13:42:29.385098+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in block in <top (required)>'
2018-07-30T13:42:29.385100+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:intap'
2018-07-30T13:42:29.385101+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `'
```

*EDIT*

I'm attaching my Gemfile

`source 'http://rubygems.org'`

gem 'rails', '3.2.21'
gem 'rake', '11.1.1'
gem 'rack-cache', '1.2'
gem 'prawn_rails'
gem 'prawn-table', '~> 0.1.2'
gem 'pg', '0.18.0'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'cocoon'
group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'uglifier'
end
gem 'browser', '1.0.0'
gem 'active_device'
gem 'minitest'
gem 'sprockets'
gem 'test-unit'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

Comment: Please provide your Gemfile content

Comment: @P.Boro just did. Sidenote, I had "gem 'prawn', '1.2.1'" instead of "gem prawn_rails". I changed it to "prawn_rails" to see if it'd make difference. It didn't.